# VS2010: Exclude a project from build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfsbuild

I have a solution that has a wcf service that connects to SQl server. When I am offline I have another service that I use for development and testing that stores to in memory storage. I would like to exclude the test service from my Team build as I do not wish to deploy this to the customer etc. How do I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In VS2010, select **Build | Configuration Manager ...**. In the Configuration Manager dialog, select  in the active configuration list. Enter a name (eg. TeamBuild) and select to copy from Release. Click **OK**.

[image]

Now make sure that only projects are checked that you want to have build a scheduled team build (exclude your test service). Click OK, save you solution and check it in.

In your Team build definition, under Build process, select the solution you just have saved and under the Configuration tab, select the TeamBuild configuration. Now, only the projects that you have selected are build.

Comment: I tried above solution, but The 'TeamBuild' configuration does not show up in Build Process/Configuration Tab. Am I missing something?

Comment: The TeamBuild configuration needs to be added by yourself, see the intstructions in the answer. It is just an example configuration name.